# what is the address pointed by file pointer?

Tags: c, file-pointer

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
     FILE *file1;
     char c;
     file1=fopen("find1.txt","r");


      if(file1==NULL)
       {
            printf("\n file doesnt exist\n");
            exit(1);
       }

      else
      {
          while(1)
          {

              c=fgetc(file1);

              if(feof(file1))
              {

                  break;
              }


             putc(c,stdout);

          }
      }


  }
```

what i think how this code  work is fgetc() take a character from file pointed by filepointer and put that character  in "c".Next time it takes the next character from the file and put that in "c". does the filepointer get increment and point to next character?or it is handeled in any other way ?

Comment: `file1` is an opaque pointer which possibly points to a `struct` which may contain many fields out of which some may have been changed. (For example incremented) on each `fgetc`

Comment: `FILE *` is just a pointer to some memory location and it won't be changed by RW operations on file. But file current position is incremented automatically after each read / write.

Comment: @serhio that means i can track the address while reading from file ?i want to find a word in a file .

Comment: The C library is designed *on purpose* to hide the contents of `FILE` from you. The only supported way to use it is with the functions in the C library. Look at the library functions for reading and setting file position.

Comment: Looks useful for file positioning information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119132/ftello-fseeko-vs-fgetpos-fsetpos

Answer (score 0):

The `file1` pointer itself does not get incremented.  The `FILE` object that it points to will contain (among other things) a pointer to the current stream position, and *that* will be updated as you read or write the file.