# C prog to read file lines between two pattern and print them out

Tags: c

I am looking for logic and code to read file and print the lines between two pattern matched. Both pattern could be in one line or may be in next consecutive line or 1st pattern appear at line number "n" and 2nd pattern appeared in line number "m" or  2nd pattern appear in line number "n" and 1st pattern appear in line number "m".

One way to achieve is to read file and track two int variable which will note the line number where first pattern match and other pattern match. For example variable x, y. x will record line# of first patter and y will record line# of second pattern, close the file. then check condition of x=y or x> y or x < y and based on that reread file and print lines between x and y or y and x. Not sure if I can reread the file before closing it or not?

Other way is to write if condition with (string compare(pattern1 with current line) || string compare (patter2 with current line) && (string compare(pattern1 with current line) || string compare (patter2 with current line)... not sure if this will work or not so need some feedback or pointers on how to achieve it in C programming.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first approach with `fpos_t` variables to track the positions in the file at which each of the patterns match, obtaining the values of those variables with `fgetpos()` when you've found a match. You can then use `fsetpos()` to set the position in the file back to the point that you recorded from the first match to re-read those lines and print out the ones you want. There is no need to close and re-open the file.

You can find information on these functions in [fgetpos/fsetpos and ftell/fseek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348637/fgetpos-fsetpos-and-ftell-fseek) and an example of using `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fsetpos/).

Comment: @devnp: If you edited your question to a minimal functional snippet of your existing code, I could suggest how `fgetpos()` etc. could be used. In fact, however, the second paragraph of your question describes exactly how these functions could be used, except you suggest using an `int`. Using an `fpos_t` instead of `int` deals with the case where the file is very long and the number of bytes exceeds the maximum value of an `int`.