# Why is the return type for ftell not fpos_t?

Tags: c, c99

According to C99, the prototype for `ftell` is:

```
long int ftell(FILE *stream);
```

From what I undersood it should be the following instead:

```
fpos_t ftell(FILE *stream);
```

Why is that?

From §7.19.1-2

> `fpos_t` which is an object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

I understand that `fpos_t` should be used to record a position within a file. So `ftell` which returns a position within a file should be of that type. Instead it is:

- `signed`
- of type `long` which can be too small or too big to access a file on certain architectures.

Comment: From where did you understand? Could you be specific?

Comment: @machine_1 I added some details

Comment: This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348637/what-is-difference-between-fgetpos-fsetpos-and-ftell-fseek) might be interesting

Comment: historical probably? `fpos_t` has been introduced later.

Comment: From **C99** §7.19.9.4 and **C11** §7.21.9.4 — The `ftell` function `long int ftell(FILE *stream);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that `fpos_t` is

> [...] a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

So it can can be even a structure, totally unusable for anything else besides calling `fsetpos`!

On the other hand the return value of `ftell` is a scalar which is guaranteed to be possible to use in telling the exact byte position in a binary file:

> For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file.

---

Other than that, the reason is *backwards-compatibility*. `ftell` debuted in C89, and perhaps then the expectation was that `long` would scale fast enough to contain all file sizes, something that is not always true nowadays. Unfortunately it is not possible to change the type returned by `ftell` but it is too late to change that now - even those platforms that support larger files now have functions with another name, such as `ftello`.

---

the signedness is required because the function returns `-1` on error.

Answer (score 6):

From the manpage of `fgetpos()/fsetpos()`:

> On some non-UNIX systems, an fpos_t object may be a complex object and these routines may be the only way to portably reposition a text stream.

whereas `ftell()` is required to return the offset of the file pointer in the file. These are completely different interfaces.

Comment: Well, I found that for `ftell()` on the return value: `Otherwise, -1 is returned and errno is set to
       indicate the error.`

Comment: @nowox Yes, correct, all these functions return `-1` to indicate an error.

Answer (score 2):

Historical reasons.

`fseek` and `ftell` are very old functions, predating C standardization. They assume that `long` is big enough to represent a position in any file -- an assumption that was probably valid at the time. `long` is at least 32 bits, and *obviously* you couldn't have a single file bigger than 2 gigabytes (or even [1.21 gigabytes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/quotes/qt0416327)).

By the time the first C standard was published (ANSI C, 1989), it was becoming obvious that this assumption was no longer valid, but changing the definitions of `fseek` and `ftell` would have broken existing code. Furthermore, there was still no integer type wider than `long` (`long long` wasn't introduced until C99).

The ANSI C committee decided that `fseek` and `ftell` were still useful, but they introduced new file positioning functions `fsetpos` and `fgetpos`. These functions use an opaque non-numeric type `fpos_t` rather than `long`, which makes them both more and less flexible than `fseek` and `ftell`. An implementation can define `fpos_t` so it can represent any possible file offset -- but since it's a non-numeric type, `fsetpos` and `fgetpos` don't provide the `SEEK_SET` / `SEEK_CUR` / `SEEK_END` feature. For example, there's no way to use `fsetpos` to position a file to its end.

Some of this is addressed in the [ANSI C Rationale, section 4.9.9](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d9.html#4-9-9):

> Given these restrictions, the Committee still felt that this function [`fseek`] has enough utility, and is used in sufficient existing code, to warrant its retention in the Standard.  `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` have been added to deal with files which are too large to handle with `fseek` and `ftell`.

If this were being defined from scratch today, there would probably be a single pair of functions covering all the functionality of the current four functions, likely using a `typedef`ed integer type required to be big enough to represent any possible file offset. (With current systems, 64 bits is likely to be sufficient, but I wouldn't be surprised to see 8-exabyte files before too long on large systems).

Answer (score 0):

The most probable use of that is to allow error return values as negative numbers.  It's the same as the `printf` family of functions, that return `ssize_t` instead of `size_t`, which happens to be a `signed` version of `size_t`.

The first of these tricks happened with `getchar()`, which returns `int` instead of `char`, to allow for the value returned on end of file condition (`EOF`) which is normally  a negative value to contrast with the whole set of possible returned characters (in the range of `0` to `255`, all positive integers)

Why don't define a signed extension of the same type to allow for `-1`?  Don't actually know :)