# How to compare 2 results of fgetpos?

Tags: c, fgets, fseek

I would like to use a `FILE*`, keep it's current position, make stuff, and compare it's new position to the previous one. Easy.

Eventually, I would like to continue my actions on this `FILE*` after an eventual relocation (move back or don't move after doing stuff). Meaning, this `FILE*` must continue leaving properly.

Example:

```
fpos_t originalPos, preBOM;
fgetpos(inFile, &originalPos);

rewind(inFile);
fgetpos(inFile, &preBOM);

unsigned char firstChar = fgetc(inFile); // Some readings...

if (originalPos != preBOM) /* Problematic comparison*/
    fsetpos(inFile, &originalPos);
```

Because of some advices (below), I put me in mind to use `fgetpos` instead of `ftell`. Maybe it's a mistake?

Mention to the `fgetpos` /vs/ `ftell` question: [what is difference between fgetpos/fsetpos and ftell/fseek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348637/what-is-difference-between-fgetpos-fsetpos-and-ftell-fseek)

The problem is I want to compare 2 "positions" which are in fact states (non trivial types) and have no comparison operator. And are not implemented the same on different compilers.

How can I compare `originalPos` to `preBOM`?

Comment: Why do you need to compare? Can't you simply call `festpos()` unconditionally?

Comment: It's a UCS-2 / utf-16 file meaning with a BOM at the beginning of the first line. If the file was given on pos 0, I want to continue working after the BOM, not at the input position.

Comment: What about `if (byte0 == 0xFE && byte1 == 0xFF) ... else if (byte0 == 0xFF && byte1 == 0xFE) ... else rewind(inFile);` ?

Comment: It's from my code, I left it unchanged to put something. I could cut the part `/*Example of stuff*/` and just leave a random `fgetc` to show I do things with the File in the middle. (so that the position changes) -- and functionality, it was a BOM detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote [from](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fpos_t/)

> The content of an fpos_t object is not meant to be read directly, but
> only to be used as an argument in a call to fsetpos.

That means, you can't compare `fpos_t`'s.

Comment: Thanks, then if I really really need to compare them, I have to use `seek/tell`.

Comment: @Sandburg I agree

Comment: @Sandburg more like "... use `fseek/ftell`".